# Cannot import librosa on SageMaker Jupyter notebook instance "OSError: sndfile library not found"

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, librosa

I am trying to import librosa on a SageMaker notebook instance but it's telling me that the sndfile library is not found. I have tried conda install -c conda-forge libsndfile but it is not working. I have been stuck on this for almost 3 hours now. Would appreciate some help. Thank you.

UPDATE (NOW WORKING):
This is what ended up working.. we had to compile the libsndfile from scrach using the following commands

```
%%bash
wget 'https://github.com/libsndfile/libsndfile/releases/download/1.0.31/libsndfile-1.0.31.tar.bz2'
tar -xf libsndfile-1.0.31.tar.bz2
cd libsndfile-1.0.31/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE (NOW WORKING): This is what ended up working.. we had to compile the libsndfile from scrach using the following commands

```
%%bash
wget 'https://github.com/libsndfile/libsndfile/releases/download/1.0.31/libsndfile-1.0.31.tar.bz2'
tar -xf libsndfile-1.0.31.tar.bz2
cd libsndfile-1.0.31/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```